# erlang protobuf error:module could not be loaded

Tags: erlang, protocol-buffers, ranch

i'm writing a erlang ranch app with protobuffs(basho), and i include the test_pb.hrl at begin,  (`include("test_pb.hrl")`). but when i make the app and run, it got the error: 
    
       `{'module could not be loaded',
       [{protobuffs,next_field_num,[<<10,5,116,101,115,116,49>>],[]},
        {test_pb,decode,3,[{file,"src/test_pb.erl"},{line,143}]},
        {test_pb,decode,2,[{file,"src/test_pb.erl"},{line,138}]},
        {reverse_protocol,handle_info,2,
            [{file,"src/reverse_protocol.erl"},{line,47}]},
        {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,604}]},
        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}`

and line,47 is :`Msgdata = test_pb:decode_test(Data),`

the whole source file is:
`
    %% Feel free to use, reuse and abuse the code in this file.

```
-module(reverse_protocol). 
-behaviour(gen_server).
-behaviour(ranch_protocol).
-import(lists, [reverse/1]).
-include("test_pb.hrl").
%% API.
-export([start_link/4]).

%% gen_server.
-export([init/1]).
-export([init/4]).
-export([handle_call/3]).
-export([handle_cast/2]).
-export([handle_info/2]).
-export([terminate/2]).
-export([code_change/3]).

-define(TIMEOUT, 5000).

-record(state, {socket, transport}).

%% API.

start_link(Ref, Socket, Transport, Opts) ->
proc_lib:start_link(?MODULE, init, [Ref, Socket, Transport, Opts]).

%% gen_server.

%% This function is never called. We only define it so that
%% we can use the -behaviour(gen_server) attribute.
init([]) -> {ok, undefined}.

init(Ref, Socket, Transport, _Opts = []) ->
ok = proc_lib:init_ack({ok, self()}),
ok = ranch:accept_ack(Ref),
ok = Transport:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
gen_server:enter_loop(?MODULE, [],
    #state{socket=Socket, transport=Transport},
    ?TIMEOUT).

handle_info({tcp, Socket, Data}, State=#state{
    socket=Socket, transport=Transport}) ->
Transport:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
io:format("receive data ~p~n", [Data]),
Msgdata = test_pb:decode_test(Data),
io:format("receive data unpack ~p~n", [Msgdata]),
Transport:send(Socket, reverse_binary(Data)),
{noreply, State, ?TIMEOUT};
handle_info({tcp_closed, _Socket}, State) ->
{stop, normal, State};
handle_info({tcp_error, _, Reason}, State) ->
{stop, Reason, State};
handle_info(timeout, State) ->
{stop, normal, State};
handle_info(_Info, State) ->
{stop, normal, State}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
{reply, ok, State}.

handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
{noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
{ok, State}.

%% Internal.

reverse_binary(B) when is_binary(B) ->
[list_to_binary(lists:reverse(binary_to_list(
    binary:part(B, {0, byte_size(B)-2})
))), "\r\n"].
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Virtual machine can't find `protobuffs` module. Try   adding `-pz deps/*/ebin` to starting options provided you have protobuffs application in your deps folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you not sure the module is loaded or not, try XXXX:module_info() in the erlang shell. If error, it is not in the path and try code:paths("xxxxxx/ebin") to add it.